# How to populate list with set of last 7 dates dynamically in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I have a current date stored in a string and I needed to pick the dates from the current date to last 7 days in a list dynamically using mongoDB objects in Java

So I have this saved in a string

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
Date s1 = cal1.getTime();

cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
String s2 = sdf.format(cal2.getTime());
```

Above, `s2` is the current date say `2014-05-12` so in a list I need to have data as below-

```
List<String> dates = {'2014-05-12', '2014-05-11','2014-05-10', '2014-05-9','2014-05-8', '2014-05-7','2014-05-6'};
```

The list dates is having all the values of last 7 days from May 6th- May 12th. (as May 12th was the current timestamp)

I wanted to populate the list with last 7 days dynamically using the current date.

Comment: you are almost there.only thing left is to write a method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String date = "2014-05-03";
    List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        Date dateParsed = sdf.parse(date);
        dateParsed.setDate(dateParsed.getDate() - i);
        dateList.add(sdf.format(dateParsed));
    }
```

This way you neither care with the month nor the year. In my example same day < 0 is converted automatically to the past month.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is confusing, the [answer by Bevilaqua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961597/642706) seems correct.

## Joda-Time

FYI, here is the same code as written by Bevilaqua but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class for when you are certain you want a date only without a time-of-day.

## ISO 8601

Since your date string is in ISO 8601 format, and Joda-Time handles the ISO 8601 formats by default, no need for parsing. Joda-Time can use its built-in default parsers.

```
String date = "2014-05-03";
LocalDate dateParsed = new LocalDate(date); // Automatically parses ISO 8601 format string.
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    LocalDate localDate = dateParsed.minusDays( i );
    dateList.add( localDate.toString() ); // By default, "toString" generates ISO 8601 format string.
}
```